# Wait for this.fs.copyTpl to complete on Yeoman Generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have the following code in my Yeoman Generator:

```
_appTemplate(src, dest, addToHG, scope) {
  let done = this.async();
  if (src === null || dest === null) {
    return;
  }

  let fullPathSrc = this.templatePath(src);
  let fullPathDest = this.destinationPath(path.join('src', dest));
  this.fs.copyTpl(fullPathSrc, fullPathDest, scope);

  if (addToHG) {
    this.log('Adding:' + fullPathDest + ' to HG now...');
    this.spawnCommand('hg', ['add', fullPathDest]).on('close', done);
  } else {
    done();
  }
}
```

But I'm seeing that the attempt to add the file to HG (mercurial) is happening too soon, the files do not exist.  How do I wait until the copyTpl is completed?

I tried the following but neither actually worked:

```
this.fs.copyTpl(fullPathSrc, fullPathDest, scope).then(() => {});
```

And

```
this.fs.copyTpl(fullPathSrc, fullPathDest, scope).on('end', () => {});
```

But nether patterns seems to be supported and I can't find the actual documentation for this.fs.copyTpl().

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course a few minutes after posting my question I find the documentation for this.fs.copyTpl().   Turns out it's an "in memory" filesystem package and doesn't commit the files to disk until later.

https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor#copyfrom-to-options

Here's a solution that works, but I don't know if it's ideal.  I'm open to suggestions here.

```
_appTemplate(src, dest, addToHG, scope) {
  let done = this.async();
  if (src === null || dest === null) {
    return;
  }

  let fullPathSrc = this.templatePath(src);
  let fullPathDest = this.destinationPath(path.join('src', dest));

  this.fs.copyTpl(fullPathSrc, fullPathDest, scope);
  this.fs.commit([], () => {
    if (addToHG) {
      this.log('Adding:' + fullPathDest + ' to HG now...');
      this.spawnCommand('hg', ['add', fullPathDest]).on('close', done);
    } else {
      done();
    }
  });
}
```